# Setting up a guest network with isolation

Tags: wireless, vlan, dhcp

Many of the wireless access points and routers now come with guest based access. However, they place the users on the same network as the private network giving them access to everything.

Do I need a specific device that separates the two? Or do I need multiple devices and configure vlans

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

This depends very much on your specific situation. Generally, most enterprise access points these days will handle multiple SSIDs and tag the different SSIDs as different VLANs, which you can then route and isolate as you would normally. If you are dealing with smaller-scale equipment such as Cisco's "small-business" line, unless the device offers some way to configure multiple SSIDs into multiple subnets (such as OpenWrt does), you'd have to use multiple access points plugged into separate switch ports.

Comment: So basically the best way is to tag SSIDs and based on the SSID tag you route it to a certain vlan?

Comment: @FrankThornton If the AP offers that functionality, that's definitely the best option. You treat that VLAN just like you would any other publicly-accessible network port (although it's best to keep wireless subnets as small as possible to reduce broadcast traffic; some recommendations now are for /27s).

Comment: We do something like this. Our APs have multiple SSIDs. Those APs are connected to our switches and the guest SSID gets it's own vlan. That vlan goes to a router in it's own VRF. At no point can the two speak to each other unless it goes through our core firewall